# Arbitrary queries on App Engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

I find myself in a need to do various datastore entries analysis from time to time. Some of the results sets I'm looking for can't be achieved by simple query on an index, thus I have to write a module for every such query, upload the code, run it and read the logs when the job's finished. I was wondering if there's simpler approach to address such issues?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/). It's designed exactly for cases like this: you can import data directly from the datastore, and run arbitrary queries on it using an SQL-like language.

Comment: It seems like I need to load the data into BigQuery every time my data updates? It makes it less than optimal for on-a-daily-basis analysis :/

Comment: I don't really understand that objection. You can load the data in every day, perhaps on a cron job. If you were doing queries all the time, I would agree it would not be viable, but loading it in daily does not seem difficult.